# Google Analytics tracks all visits to '/', unless it has a parameter

Tags: google-analytics

This site is a Wordpress/WooCommerce-page, - so it has many different 'real' URL's.

In my Google Analytics-report, then the numbers under 'Behaviour' >> 'Overview' (and in '**Behaviour**' >> '**Site Content**' >> '**All Pages**' for that matter) is looking wierd. If I have it shown as '**Page**' then it bulks all visits that doesn't have a parameter (such as `?s=search_term` or `?key=order_number`) - and shows them all as visits to `/`. Example:

[image: Google Analytics - Page]

But if I click on '**Page title**' instead, then the distribution is shown correctly (but I can, for obvious reason, not see the URL, which is annoying):

[image: Google Analytics - Page title]

If I add the secondary dimension '**URL Destination**', then it's just shown as `not set`.

[image: Google Analytics - Page title with URL as secondary dimension]

How do I get 'the regular' (The page-view) to work? And why does this occur?

Comment: Do your pages actually have different Urls (eg. if this is some kind of SPA that changes only the part after a #hashmark to denote url changes GA will happily ignore that) ? I think this is not answerable without knowing more about your site and customisations to your tracking code (if any).

Comment: I just added an important comment at the top, - cause that was a good point, you made. It's a Wordpress/WooCommerce-page, - so it has many real pages.

Comment: Can you look at your network tab or use the Google Analytics debugger extension to see if the Urls are actually sent to GA ? If no then you need to look at your tracking code (that would suggest that either the page path or the location field are overwritten), if yes then you'd need to look at our view filters to see if the "request url" field is changed via a filter.

Comment: The URL's are sent (I both checked with the debugger, - but i can also see them in the 'Page title'-tab). I then went in and grabbed a new GA-tracking code and compared it to the current one, - and they identical. And if I go to 'Admin' >> 'Filters' (for the view), - then I can only see the one filter that excludes my own IP-address. 
   Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Not really. I might be able to tell you why "destinantion url" shows nothing, because that refers to the destination urls for Google Adwords ads ( a dimension that is imported from linked Adwords accounts when you use autotagging), so unless you were expecting Adwords traffic it is normal that this is not set (also the process that mangles your Urls might strip off the glcid parameter for Adwords traffic so it is no longer recognized). I assume a link to your site would be out of the question - this is quite an intriguing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed syntax for "classic" Google Analytics and Universal Analytics. Also you are overriding the page path.

This is a screenshot from your code (tracking id removed):

[image]

[This is "old" syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/). This still works and would not per se be a problem if you did not try to call Enhanced E-Ecommerce functions in the code that do not work with classic ga:

[image]

This creates a reference error:

[image]

The classic code has a variable that is called "ga", but that is not the same as  the ga object in Universal Analytics (and also it sits inside a self executing function and is thus not available in the global scope).

The culprit for your page path problem however is this line:

```
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview", "/"]);
```

By setting the second argument to "/" you override the current page path and set it to "/" for all your Urls.

You should update your ga code with current Universal analytics code and not set a page path (i.e. do not provide a custom page to the send pageview call):

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```